# Comment to notify several users?

Tags: feature-request, support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

1. I was wondering where I can find
   some info about how to make a
   comment and notify several users?

   > @tom @tim: blah blah...

   seems to just notify the last user tim,
   according to one post I have read
   before.
2. How to reply to all the users who
   have commented after the same
   question/reply? Will things similar
   to this work?

   > @all: blah blah...

---

I actually read the link before I posted. I am not sure if I have understood that link. So are the two cases above both impossible? If not, is it reasonable to implement such function? I feel this will be helpful when one wants to comment the same thing to several users and repeat the comment with each user will make the thread unnecessarily long.

Comment: I read the link you gave but not sure if I understand correctly. Are the two cases I mentioned both impossible?

Comment: "@tom @tim" is equivalent to just "@tom"; later @s are meaningless. "@all" does nothing, unless there happens to be a user named "all"

Comment: Can I change my post to feature request and will you reopen my question?

Comment: (Or a user named Allen, Allon, Ally, allesubuntu, allesklar, ...)