# What do I do wrong here: only one additional user can be notified, "additional" means one more, right? Wrong?

Tags: support, comment-replies

I receive the following message when I have one additional user. I have one user that I notified (@waffles) and one additional user that I notified (@Bo P).

I'm pretty sure that I misinterpret the message  — please confirm because otherwise it's a bug — but shouldn't it then be read as "Only one user can be notified adjacent to the post owner, please remove second @+name". The current message confuses me, I understand it that a new feature was introduced that allows me to notify *two* people (as everyone already knows the post owner will be notified, this is ignored).

[image]

Comment: I agree that the message is bad.  Only one user *is* being at-notified, the other is notified separately.  The message should be something like `The post owner will always be notified, and only one additional user can be @notified`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Two @/ats, One comment… Change the message?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103476)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It uses the term "additional" as the owner of the post is **always** notified of comments posted regardless of any "@user" notification. This is the meaning of the message, though it is clumsily worded.

So in this case the following people would be notified:

1. The post owner.
2. waffles.

Bo P would never get notified therefore allowing the post to go through would give the commenter (you) a misleading impression that they had been notified as well.

A better wording might be:

> <strike>Only one additional user can be notified via the @user syntax; the post owner will always be notified.</strike>
>
> The @user syntax can only be used to notify one user per comment; post owners are always notified of new comments

You could argue that it should warn but still let you post, but that's a different question.

Comment: Or perhaps "The @user syntax can only be used to notify one user per comment; post owners are always notified of new comments" for a mere 11 characters more.

Comment: @Tim - that works for me!

Comment: @Tim: I like yours more as the word "additional" implies for me that you can add _one more_ (without saying from what number it starts counting). In other words: "additional" is, whatever the wording, always ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it's considered as by-design. You can't notify 2 users at once. It's strange, but that's it

See

- [Don't tell me how to write! ("Only one additional @user can be notified" message)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103587/dont-tell-me-how-to-write-only-one-additional-user-can-be-notified-message)
- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)
- [Comment to notify several users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85767/comment-to-notify-several-users)

Comment: The bug is the strange wording of the message.

Comment: @Paŭlo: indeed, the message is ambiguous at best.