# Can we add the ability to notify an editor in a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

We have the ability to notify a commenter via the `@somebody` syntax, which is very useful to update on the comments others have left. I've seen the suggestions from people about being able to notify "anyone", like [this one to notify many users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85767/comment-to-notify-several-users), and the [ones about notifying the OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52368/does-op-also-notify-the-op)...

What I'd like to do is be able to notify someone who has made an edit on, but not commented on, a question.

I've been working on removal/management of the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag on SO, and I *frequently* see new questions that have recently been edited by users to add the homework tag. [Here's a recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502003/mysql-how-to-get-average-from-this-column). I'd love the ability to just `@` them in the comments asking them to stop, but as far as I know, today, I can't do this unless they comment as well as edit it.

Comment: For quick reference: "You can explicitly notify one (1) other commenter, **editor**, or ♦ moderator who closed a question." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Related: [Expand the username auto-completion to everyone who can be notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106534)

Comment: I ran a test and unless a person have commeneted you cannot send them a "commen message" -- hence sending a message to somebody who have only edited a question is not possible -- **so I don't think this is a duplicate**